# Hidden Flexbox Elements w/ jQuery Visibility Toggle - How to Keep Proper Positioning

Tags: css, flexbox

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qtsoo4w5/2/

I'm using Flexbox to display three cards (*.column-layout-card*'s) per row, in   a container.

For every fourth card (first in the beginning of a row), I'm setting the `margin-left` to 0, and for each card after the first row, I'm adding `margin-top: 25px`. This works well, as more cards are dynamically added to the container.

Now, I'm working on a "flip" effect, where you click a button on the card and another card takes its place. This card (w/ added class *.column-layout-card-instructions*) will follow directly after in the markup and will be set to `display: none` until it's triggered by the button click.

The hidden card gets counted just like all the others in my CSS. So, for example, because it might be the first card in a row, it could get `margin-left: 0` -- but because it's actually replacing the third card in the previous row, it needs to have the left margin that a third card would normally have. I've been able to fix this by creating a script that copies the margin of the current card, assigns it to the hidden card, and then toggles.

The problem is that the hidden card still messes up the order of the cards and as a result messes up the positioning of the cards around it.

CSS:

```
.info-cards .column-layout-card:nth-child(3n+1) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.info-cards > .column-layout-card:nth-child(n+4) {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
```

Comment: What about adding your margins using JS, and then you can use jQuery's [`:visible` selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) along with your `:nth-of-type`'s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't aware that nth-child and nth-of-type could not be applied to specific classes.

What worked for me was to instead use a `section` instead of a `div` for *.column-layout-card-instructions*, and then swap my CSS to:

```
.info-cards > div:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
    margin-left: 0;
}

.info-cards > div:nth-of-type(n+4) {
    margin-top: 25px;
}
```

It's a little bit hacky, but it does the job. If anyone has a more elegant solution, I'll hold off counting my response as correct for a while.